# How to randomly move an image around a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image in the cell of a table and I want it to move from one cell to another at random. I was planning on using the setInterval and Math.random() to move the image around randomly every two seconds but I cannot get the image to move around at all

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        tr { width: 300px; height: 100px }
        td { width: 100px; height: 100px }
        img { width: 100px; height: 100px }
    </style>
        <script> 
            function moveImgRandomly()
            {


            }
        </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <table border=1 id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><img src="http://graemehobbs93.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/ape-1.jpg" id="img"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

This is what I have so far that works. I have been trying for hours to get the image to move and it will not. I also cannot use jQuery.

Comment: your moveImgRandomly function is empty, what code have you tried to put in there?

Comment: you plan it.but where is the code for `setInterval` and `Math.random()`.try it yourself first

Comment: so select the image and append it to another cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("img");
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

setInterval(function(){
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * tds.length);
 tds[randomNumber].appendChild(img);
}, 2000);
```

```css
tr { width: 300px; height: 100px }
td { width: 100px; height: 100px }
img { width: 100px; height: 100px }
```

```html
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <table border=1 id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><img src="http://graemehobbs93.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/ape-1.jpg" id="img"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Great, but I'd rather see `var tds = document.getElementByTagName('myTable').getElementsByTagName("td");` to get just the cells of the subject table. ;-)

Comment: Yes this should be changed if you intend to add more tables wich shouldn't be affected by the random image change. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clearAll(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML="<p></p>";
  }
}


setInterval(function(){ 
  clearAll();
                        var elements =            document.getElementsByTagName('td');
                        var ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
                    elements[ind].innerHTML ='<img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com/help/images/photo_border.png" >';
                      }, 3000);
```

```css
tr { height: 100px};
td { width: 100px; height: 100px; display:block; };
img { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
td p {
  padding:100px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```